# How to create a custom enumerator for a class derived from TDictionary?

Tags: delphi, enumerator, tdictionary

I have defined a collection derived from TDictionary, and need to define a custom enumerator that apply an additional filter.

I'm stuck as I can't access the TDictionary FItems array (it is private) so I can't define the MoveNext method

How would you proceed to redefine a filtered enumerator on a class derived from TDictionary?

Here's a simple code to illustrate what I want to do:

```
TMyItem = class(TObject)
public
  IsHidden:Boolean; // The enumerator should not return hidden items
end;
TMyCollection<T:TMyItem> = class(TDictionary<integer,T>)
public
   function GetEnumerator:TMyEnumerator<T>; // A value filtered enumerator
   type
     TMyEnumerator = class(TEnumerator<T>)
     private
       FDictionary: TMyCollection<integer,T>;
       FIndex: Integer;
       function GetCurrent: T;
     protected
       function DoGetCurrent: T; override;
       function DoMoveNext: Boolean; override;
     public
       constructor Create(ADictionary: TMyCollection<integer,T>);
       property Current: T read GetCurrent;
       function MoveNext: Boolean;
     end;
end;

function TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
// In below code, FIndex is not accessible, so I can't move forward until my filter applies
  while FIndex < Length(FDictionary.FItems) - 1 do   
  begin
    Inc(FIndex);
    if (FDictionary.FItems[FIndex].HashCode <> 0) 
      and not(FDictionary.FItems[FIndex].IsHidden) then // my filter
      Exit(True);
  end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can base your Enumerator on `TDictionary`'s enumerator, so you don't actually need access to `FItems`. This works even if you write a wrapper class around `TDictionary` as Barry suggests. The enumerator would look like this:

```
TMyEnumerator = class
protected
  BaseEnumerator: TEnumerator<TPair<Integer, T>>; // using the key and value you used in your sample
public
  function MoveNext:Boolean;
  property Current:T read GetCurrent;
end;

function TMyEnumerator.MoveNext:Boolean;
begin
  Result := BaseEnumerator.MoveNext;
  while Result and (not (YourTestHere)) do // ie: the base enumerator returns everything, reject stuff you don't like
    Result := BaseEnumerator.MoveNext;
end;

function TMyEnumerator.Current: T;
begin
  Result := BaseEnumerator.Current.Value; // Based on your example, it's value you want to extract
end;
```

And here's a complete, 100 lines console application that demonstrates this:

```
program Project23;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections;

type

  TMyType = class
  public
    Int: Integer;
    constructor Create(anInteger:Integer);
  end;

  TMyCollection<T:TMyType> = class(TDictionary<integer,T>)
  strict private
    type
      TMyEnumerator = class
      protected
        BaseEnum: TEnumerator<TPair<Integer,T>>;
        function GetCurrent: T;
      public
        constructor Create(aBaseEnum: TEnumerator<TPair<Integer,T>>);
        destructor Destroy;override;

        function MoveNext:Boolean;
        property Current:T read GetCurrent;
      end;
  public
    function GetEnumerator: TMyEnumerator;
  end;

{ TMyCollection<T> }

function TMyCollection<T>.GetEnumerator: TMyEnumerator;
begin
  Result := TMyEnumerator.Create(inherited GetEnumerator);
end;

{ TMyType }

constructor TMyType.Create(anInteger: Integer);
begin
  Int := anInteger;
end;

{ TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator }

constructor TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator.Create(aBaseEnum: TEnumerator<TPair<Integer, T>>);
begin
  BaseEnum := aBaseEnum;
end;

function TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator.GetCurrent: T;
begin
  Result := BaseEnum.Current.Value;
end;

destructor TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator.Destroy;
begin
  BaseEnum.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TMyCollection<T>.TMyEnumerator.MoveNext:Boolean;
begin
  Result := BaseEnum.MoveNext;
  while Result and ((BaseEnum.Current.Value.Int mod 2) = 1) do
    Result := BaseEnum.MoveNext;
end;

var TMC: TMyCollection<TMyTYpe>;
    V: TMyType;

begin
  try
    TMC := TMyCollection<TMyType>.Create;
    try
      // Fill TMC with some values
      TMC.Add(1, TMyType.Create(1));
      TMC.Add(2, TMyType.Create(2));
      TMC.Add(3, TMyType.Create(3));
      TMC.Add(4, TMyType.Create(4));
      TMC.Add(5, TMyType.Create(5));
      TMC.Add(6, TMyType.Create(6));
      TMC.Add(7, TMyType.Create(7));
      TMC.Add(8, TMyType.Create(8));
      // Filtered-enum
      for V in TMC do
        WriteLn(V.Int);
      ReadLn;
    finally TMC.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for this complete example, I have a better understanding now on how to use enumerators. I also discovered that wrapping enumerators has a huge performance penalty (in my sample application, an object query takes 2.2ms with the regular TDictionary enumerator, 3.3ms (+50%!) with the wrapped enumerator, without applying any filter).

Comment: @user315561, what takes 2.2ms? 2.2 ms on a modern CPU is an awful long time, you probably miss-calculated something; And that renders the 3.3ms result for the wrapped enumerator equally wrong.

Comment: I agree that my figures, provided out of context, are not relevant. The use case is a query on a collection of 75000 objects, browsed sequentially with a simple equality filter, and 850 matching objects added to a new result collection. What I wanted to highlight here is the cost penalty of the enumerator wrapping (on the very same use case), which is relevant and good to know.

Comment: Be aware that this approach will break if a reference of type `TMyCollection<T>` is assigned to a location of type `TDictionary<Integer,T>`, and `GetEnumerator` is subsequently called via that location, because it will call the `TDictionary<Integer,T>` version of `GetEnumerator`. This is just one manifestation of why it's a bad idea not to wrap the type instead.

Answer (score 4):

You should write a class that wraps `TDictionary` rather than inherits from it directly. The only reason `TDictionary` can be inherited from at all is so that `TObjectDictionary` could be defined and stay polymorphic with it. That is, the only proper support through overriding `TDictionary` is to customize what happens when keys and values are removed from the dictionary (so they might need to be freed).

Comment: Thanks Barry, good recommendation. The other advantage will be to make my collection less coupled to the dictionary choice, making it easier to replace it with a higher performance dict when available